# how to zip folder in ubuntu lamp

Tags: ubuntu, gzip, tar

Im new in Ubuntu.

What I want to achieve is to zip a folder located at the `var/www/html` directory.
How can I do this? What are the certain cli commands I'm gonna use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with LAMP. But, under Ubuntu, gzip cannot be used to zip folders. Instead, we'll use the tar command:

```
tar -czvf yourzip.tar.gz directory_to_zip/
```

The flags we're using are as follows:

1. -c Create an archive from the files in directory_to_zip/.
2. -z Use the gzip algorithm.
3. -f Store the output as a file. (In the above example, that file will be yourzip.tar.gz.)
4. -v Provide verbose output as it runs.

If all you wanted was to just compress a single file, you could just use gzip on that file without any flags needed, and it'll automatically be created as a .gz file (not .tar.gz).